# asymetric encryption of directory

Tags: linux, encryption

Currently I am wondering whether it is possible to apply asymetric encryption of a directory in Linux.

I would like to achieve the following:

- Write log files to /var/log/secret
- Everything written to /var/log/secret is instantly encrypted by a public RSA key (or something similar)

The encryption programms I know, i.e. ecryptfs do not support asymetric encryption of files, at least as far as I know. (Correct me if I am wrong). Therefore I am asking here whether you know of any possibility to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a reason encryption programs don't do asymmetric encryption on the file system. It's extremely slow. Even SSL/TLS (arguably the best known implementation of public key crypto) only uses it for initial handshake and then switches to symmetric.

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible for small amounts of data? Lets say about 200 MB a day???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GPG manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Examples.html) claims it can encrypt files for Bob using Bob's public key.